# Issue with Assigning Toggle buttons to Class Module

Tags: vba, excel, class

Can anybody help me what I did wrong here? the controls are not attaching to the Class!

My Class Module: **CTglBtn**

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents tgl1 As MSForms.ToggleButton
Private ac$

Public Property Get ACNumber() As String
    ACNumber = ac
End Property

Public Property Let ACNumber(value As String)
    ac = value
End Property

Private Sub tgl1_Click()
' do something here
End Sub
```

and here is where I am assigning the controls of my form to the class.

```
Dim Ctgl As CTglBtn
Dim Coll As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim aclist As Range

Set aclist = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("panel").Range("acnum")

    For i = 1 To 10
        Set Ctgl = New CTglBtn
        Set Ctgl.tgl1 = Me.Controls("TB" & i)
        Ctgl.ACNumber = aclist.Cells(i + 1, 1)
        Me.Controls("TB" & i).Caption = Ctgl.ACNumber
        Coll.Add Ctgl
        Set Ctgl = Nothing
    Next
'        MsgBox Coll.Count
    End Sub
```

Comment: I forgot to add this line:

Set Coll = New Collection
the issue is over now. Thanks Rory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim Coll As Collection` needs to be a module-level declaration, otherwise it is cleared as soon as the routine ends.

You also need to initialize that variable:

```
Set coll = New Collection
```

Comment: yes, I tried it as public variable or Module-Level. I tried both. but on debugging the issue is before the collection code occurs! even the property is not passed to the class instance

Comment: It is not public in the code you posted. If that's not your actual code, it really doesn't help anyone to help you! If you **know** the issue is somewhere else (it doesn't appear to be from what you posted), why not tell us where?!

Comment: Thanks for the note. I tried all of this. and this was one of the iterations actually.

Comment: I actually said that the controls are not attaching to the class. It is my understanding. I am a Nobis, unfortunately, I don't know more. I just know I have other applications that work exactly same!

Comment: Just edited the answer - I thought you had initialised the collection, but you haven't.

Comment: Yes Exactly. Thanks again.